# MapStruct: Mapping of Object class

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
Class Source {
   private String type;
   private Object identifier;
}
```

The identifier could be an object of class **AppointmentIdentifier or JobIdentifier**;
I have to map Source to Target, which has below structure.

```
Class Target {
    private String type;
    private Object identifierBO;
}
```

The identifierBO could an object of class **AppointmentIdentifierBO or JobIdentifierBO**.
Below is my Mapper class:

```
@Mapper
public interface ModelMapper {

    Target toTarget(@NonNull final Source source);

    AppointmentIdentifierBO toAppointmentIdentifierBO(AppointmentIdentifier appointmentIdentifier);

    JobBO toJobBO(JobIdentifier jobIdentifier);
}
```

I know, I am missing some configuration which will help mapping identifier to identifierBO, but could not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know this way to do this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface ModelMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "identifier", target = "identifierBO", qualifiedByName = "identifierMapping")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    @Named("identifierMapping")
    default Object mapIdentifier(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof AppointmentIdentifier)
            return toAppointmentIdentifierBO((AppointmentIdentifier) obj);

        if (obj instanceof JobIdentifier)
            return toJobBO((JobIdentifier) obj);

        throw new RuntimeException("Not supported type: " + obj.getClass());
    }

    AppointmentIdentifierBO toAppointmentIdentifierBO(AppointmentIdentifier appointmentIdentifier);

    JobBO toJobBO(JobIdentifier jobIdentifier);
}
```

Horrible? Yes. Works? Yes.

Comment: Why horrible? If you only have Object there is no other way. This answer is great, everything done like it should be done with MapStruct (IMO)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of using @AfterMapping function with the same code that you have written inside mapIdentifier. It would have been great if MapStruct could have understood the instance of the Object.

Comment: MapStruct is an annotation processor, it doesn't do anything on runtime. Therefore, it is not possible for MapStruct to understand the instance of the Object. There is a request for Type-Refinement (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131). However, even with that we most certainly won't look for all possible instances of `Object`

Comment: @Shadov: The code is not working, as I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Not supported type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap`. Inside mapIdentifier method, I converted the Object to AppointmentIdentifier through Jackson ObjectMapper.

Comment: You didn't use Jackson right then, basically Jackson converts to `LinkedHashMap` whenever it cannot convert to the correct type. Also this looks weird, you alread have an `Object`, why do you need Jackson? Jackson is for `String->Object` conversion and the other way around. Make separate question, link here, we will help.